# Haskell: Is there a 'getLine' analog that passes the contents of a file path from user input to a variable?

Tags: haskell, io

Something like

```
>> l1 <- getContents_fu
(this line is user input) dir/file.txt
>> putStrLn l1
These are the contents of 'file.txt'.
```

I suppose the type signature can be **String** so long as the returned string is the contents of file.txt.

Comment: `getLine >>= readFile`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @AlexisKing

Answer (score 1):

As observed in the comments, `getLine >>= readFile` does this and has type `IO String`. Here is a sample shell interaction.

```
$ cat > file.txt
Hello from a file!
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> contentsFromName = getLine >>= readFile
contentsFromName :: IO String
ghci > contentsFromName
file.txt
"Hello from a file!\n"
```